# Magento credit memo get offline or online refund status

Tags: magento, credits

I'm trying to add to the PDF creditmemo rather the refund was given offline or online.

How do I get this information from the creditmemo?

I've tried to use the method getTotalOfflineRefunded() but it comes back null everytime.

Is there an arg for getData() I can use to get this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you are searching for, are saved on the order not on the creditmemo

In the creditmemo model(`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo`) you will find something like this

```
$this->getOrder()->setTotalOfflineRefunded(
    $this->getOrder()->getTotalOfflineRefunded()-$this->getGrandTota 
);
$this->getOrder()->setBaseTotalOfflineRefunded(
    $this->getOrder()->getBaseTotalOfflineRefunded()-$this->getBaseGrandTotal()   
);
```

So to get the total offline refunded you should try this:

```
 $order->load('{orderId}')->getBaseTotalOfflineRefunded();
```

In case the difference between `getBaseTotalOfflineRefunded()` and `getTotalOfflineRefunded()` is not clear:
**Base** always indicates the order amount in your "base" currency, while the other method gets the amount in the currency of the store where the order was placed in.

Comment: Thanks Fantus! it's interesting that all the refund values would be tied to the order and not the creditmemo.